# How to send an Exception object from GWT's client to server?

Tags: java, gwt, exception

I'm trying to log client's exceptions on the server side. So I need to send them from client to server.

I have created service for this purpose:

```
public interface LoggerService extends RemoteService {
    void logerror(Throwable e);
}
```

On the client's side I use  GWT.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(uncaughtExceptionHandler):

```
GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler uncaughtExceptionHandler = new
    GWT.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
          public void onUncaughtException(Throwable e) {

            LoggerServiceAsync loggerService = GWT.create(LoggerService.class);
            loggerService.logerror(e, new AsyncCallback<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void arg0) {
                    SC.say("Client's error logged");

                }
                @Override
                public void onFailure(Throwable arg0) {
                    SC.say("Unable to log client's error");

                }
            });  
          }
        };
```

When I'm using hosted mode it works fine. But when I'm trying to work with web mode My LoggerService doesn't work. I know that in hosted mode exception "translates" from js to java. But I can't understand, why my logerror(Throwable e) method doesn't invoke at all in web mode. Server responce is 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I added [gwt-log](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/) for logging client's exceptions on server.

Answer (score 0):

GWT offers infrastructure that facilitates client side [logging](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html) with [support](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html#Remote_Logging) for sending your log messages to the server. It'll slightly complicate your implementation at first but might establish a way to do logging across your app.

Comment: thanks, will try this tomorrow, looks like it is what i'm looking for

Comment: Is there any way to get "normal" java stacktrace using GWT logging in web mode?